# SQL Server Lookup Functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to build lookup type functions in SQL Server or are these always inferior (performance) to just writing subqueries/joins?

I would like to take some code like this

```
SELECT
    ContactId,
    ProductType,
    SUM(OrderAmount) TotalOrders
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ContactId,
            ProductType,
            OrderAmount
        FROM
            UserOrders ord
            JOIN
            (
                SELECT
                    ProductCode,
                    CASE
                        --Complex business logic
                    END ProductType
                FROM
                    ItemTable
            ) item
            ON
                item.ProductCode=ord.ProductCode

    ) a
GROUP BY
    ContactId,
    ProductType
```

And instead be able to write a query like this

```
SELECT
    ContactId,
    UDF_GET_PRODUCT(ProductCode) ProductType,
    SUM(OrderAmount) TotalOrders
FROM
    UserOrders
GROUP BY
    ContactId,
    UDF_GET_PRODUCT(ProductCode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not quite in the format you have described. Whether it is advisable or not really depends.

I agree with the other answer in that scalar functions are performance killers, and I personally do not use them at all. 
That being said I don't think that is a reason to ignore the DRY principle where feasible. i.e. I would not take a short cut 
if it had an impact on performance, however I also don't like the idea of having complex logic repeated in multiple places.
When anything changes you then have multiple queries to change, and inevitably some get missed, so if you will be re-using this
logic then it is a good idea to encapsulate it in a single place.

Based on your example perhaps a view would be most appropriate:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ItemTableWithLogic
AS
    SELECT  ProductCode,
            ProductType = <your logic>
    FROM    ItemTable;
```

Then you can simply use:

```
SELECT  ord.ContactId, item.ProductType, SUM(ord.OrderAmount) AS TotalOrders
FROM    UserOrders AS ord
        INNER JOIN dbo.ItemTableWithLogic AS item
            ON item.ProductCode=ord.ProductCode
GROUP BY ord.ContactId, item.ProductType;
```

Which simplifies things somewhat.

Another alternative is an inline table valued function, something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetProductType (@ProductCode INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(   SELECT  ProductType = <your logic>
    FROM    ItemTable
    WHERE   ProductCode = @ProductCode
);
```

Which can be called using:

```
SELECT  ord.ContactId, item.ProductType, SUM(ord.OrderAmount) AS TotalOrders
FROM    UserOrders AS ord
        CROSS APPLY dbo.ItemTableWithLogic(ord.ProductCode) AS item
GROUP BY ord.ContactId, item.ProductType;
```

My preference is for views over table valued functions, however, it would really depend on your usage as to which I would recommend, so I don't really want to pick a side, I will stick to sitting on the fence.

In summary, If you only need to use the logic in one place, and won't need to reuse it in many queries then just stick to a subquery. If you need to reuse the same logic multiple times, don't use a scalar valued function in the same way you might in a procedural language, but also don't let this rule out other ways of keeping your logic in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

Stick to sub-queries and Joins.

Because it would use a set based approach and execute the inner query once , apply aggregate on to the result set returned from the inner query and return the final result set.

On the other hand if you use a Scalar function like you have shown in your second query, all the code inside the function (sub-query in your original question) will be executed for the each row returned.

Scalar functions are performance killers and should avoid them whenever possible. This is the .net mentality that if you are having to write a piece of a code again and again put it inside a method and call the method, not true for sql server.